# Как из такого массива получить максимальное и минимальное значение в массиве?

Tags: javascript

```js
let data = [
  [
    [],
    [{'delta': 4.58}],
    [{'delta': 3.17}]
  ],
  [
    [{'delta': 9.58}],
    [{'delta': 7.21}],
    [{'delta': 1.17}]
  ],
  [
    [{'delta': 11.51}],
    [],
    [{'delta': 3.08}]
  ]
];
console.log(data);
let min = 0; // ?
let max = 0; // ?
```

Comment: Такая функция почему то не прокатывает `Math.max(...data.map(e => e.delta));`

Comment: А стандартные алгоритмы не пробовал?

Comment: @Sire IMPACTUS, а какие есть?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Твоя функция "не прокатывает" потому что элементами массива являются массивы, а не объекты с нужными полями.

В качестве решения можно воспользоваться методом [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) приводящим массив к одному уровню и лишь затем методом map получать значения нужных полей

```js
let data = [
  [
    [],
    [{
      'delta': 4.58
    }],
    [{
      'delta': 3.17
    }]
  ],
  [
    [{
      'delta': 9.58
    }],
    [{
      'delta': 7.21
    }],
    [{
      'delta': 1.17
    }]
  ],
  [
    [{
      'delta': 11.51
    }],
    [],
    [{
      'delta': 3.08
    }]
  ]
];

console.log(Math.max(...data.flat(2).map(el => el.delta)))
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
let data = [
  [
    [],
    [{'delta': 4.58}],
    [{'delta': 3.17}]
  ],
  [
    [{'delta': 9.58}],
    [{'delta': 7.21}],
    [{'delta': 1.17}]
  ],
  [
    [{'delta': 11.51}],
    [],
    [{'delta': 3.08}]
  ]
];

const newData = data.flat(Infinity);

console.log('max', newData.reduce((prev, current) => (prev.delta > current.delta) ? prev : current))
console.log('min', newData.reduce((prev, current) => (prev.delta > current.delta) ? current : prev))
```